# Time period of Kapila muni

Tags: scripture, bhagavata-purana, manuscripts, kapila

If Kapila muni lived during Svayambhuva-manvantara, did he live approximately 426 Maha-yugas back?.

Reasons for this question:

> Current Manu is 7/14. Swayambhu Manu is 1/14. Each Manu rules 71 Maha-yugas

So 71×6 = 426 Maha-yugas.

Comment: You forgot to take into account the period of "sandhya" and "sandhyaamsa" that precedes and procedes each of the manvantara

Comment: +27 magayugas as we have already crossed them. And are currently in 28th

Comment: Yes exactly, so was he living 453 Maha-yugas back?. Scriptures portray he lived during Satya-yug. I misunderstood that he lived during the current Maha-yuga's Satya yug.